# Converting dimensions into metrics of AUT type

Tags: looker-studio

I am using my personal data to create visualization report and following is the snapshot of my schema.

[image]

Field & Field 2 both are having numeric values. I would like to know why they are treated as dimensions and not metrics. Moreover if I am getting numeric values as dimension how to convert them in metrics (AUT type)?

if it is not possible, how to create time series chart for individual data points without applying any metrics function like sum,avg.?

Sample Data:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"**Green**" Number fields are currently the expected output (thus, in this scenario, the `field1` Number field displayed as a "**Green**" Dimension is the intended behaviour), so the "**Green**" Number Dimensions could be used in the Metric section of the chart. It was part of the [31 Oct 2019 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9691261#oct-31-2019) to Google Data Studio, which "*[Improved data modeling in Data Sources](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6402048?ref_topic=7441655)"*. Quoting from the release notes in the [Announcing data modeling improvements (02 Nov 2019)](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/18307022) article:

> You don't need to take any action. Charts and calculated fields used
> in your reports will work as before the upgrade. However, if you
> create or edit data sources from flexible schema (or tabular) data
> sets, such as Sheets or BigQuery, you may notice that number fields
> that previously appeared as metrics (blue fields) with an aggregation
> of None now appear as green dimensions with a new Default Aggregation
> of Sum. This change has no effect in existing charts, but makes it
> easier to use these fields in more flexible ways.

"**Blue**" Metric fields would be values that are pre-aggregated, such as the `Record Count` field, Metrics in the Google Analytics Data Source, or it can be achieved by creating an [Aggregated](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9320174) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in your respective Data Source such as `SUM(field1)` which would be displayed as a "Blue" Metric and the `AUT` type (also, adding the "Green" Number fields to the Metric section of a chart would automatically add a default aggregation of `SUM` and turn the field colour to "**Blue**").

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/6660ab37-b053-4eb9-ae32-d6981ccf4729) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QVKS2_m81x4OlojWg3zAoIdJRmrlNr9vmAeXIz9lsI0/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]